# How to adjust S Pen pressure sensitivity on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1?

Tags: settings, stylus, peripherals, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, s-pen

A little background on me: I'm a professional cartoonist and have been working digital for about 20 years. I've had numerous Wacom devices & currently enjoy a Cintiq 21UX (older model). I also have the ASUS EP121 Slate. I think I understand Wacoms pretty well and generally don't panic about computer stuff.

The Samsung Note 10.1 S Pen is using Wacom's *penabled* tech. Same kind of hardware in the ASUS EP 121.

With every Wacom device I've used to date, either Mac or Windows, there is a control panel dialogue box that allows you to tweak the pressure settings of the pen so that the artist/user has the best control for them. The S Pen does not have this and I want it! :)

I have called Wacom. They said they provided the hardware but do not provide support for it. I called Samsung who said it was an Android operating system issue. Before I begin another round of waiting on hold hoping for Android support I thought I'd try here.

Any assistance or at least firm Android tech suppport numbers I could call would be much appreciated. I realize the Note 10.1 is brand new tech and a proper driver solution may be a few updates away but I am willing to be a squeaky wheel and/or early adopter to help this happen :)

Comment: XDA has a [forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1964551) with a similar question. There are more threads, just search the Note's forum for pressure or so.

Comment: You can try this http://galaxy-note2.wonderhowto.com/how-to/adjust-your-samsung-galaxy-notes-s-pen-sensitivity-for-better-touch-response-0140084/

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after asking the question and existing answers have no votes). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Only chinese tablet Eben T6 or T7 provide a better solution of Wacom S pen, Samsung has no development of Wacom pen pressure tuning at all and make it no much different from a capasitive pen

Comment: Do you have sources? The fact that the tablet uses Wacom's technology which does have pressure control suggests that it can be done on a Samsung tablet, perhaps not with their OS but certainly on that tablet.